# Python: Using pandas to import csv. Trying to plot a column but gives me an error saying "no numerical data to plot"

Tags: python, csv, pandas, plot

I'm trying to read following csv-file with pandas and plot a column of it:

```
data type,approved mining area,mined area,coal content,earth rate,coal rate,waste ratio
unit,ha,ha,Mt,Mm3/a,Mt/a,
Garzweiler,11400,3096,1246,140,37.5,4.4
Hambach,8500,4224,1500,275,40,5.2
Inden,4500,1655,358,87.5,22.5,3.6
```

which gives me the following (only a part so it fits here):

```
data type approved mining area mined area coal content earth rate  \
 0        unit                   ha         ha           Mt      Mm3/a   
 1  Garzweiler                11400       3096         1246        140   
 2     Hambach                 8500       4224         1500        275   
 3       Inden                 4500       1655          358       87.5
```

my code is the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=",")

df["coal content"][1:4].plot()
```

if i `print df.["coal content"][1:4]` it gives me numeric values only (1246, 1500, 358), but trying to plot it gives me the following error:

> TypeError: Empty 'Series': no numeric data to plot

i have searched the web, but was not able to find a solution. i found a similar problem where "," were used in the data instead of "." - but that is not the case in this data set, especially not in this row.

any help?

Comment: Your csv doesn't appear to be using commas as a separator, it's really unclear what your heading column names are

Comment: Are you sure they are not parsed as String

Comment: Sorry, i only showed the parsed output of the imported csv - now i added the initial csv file. And how can i be sure to not parse it as a string? Sorry I am very new to programming and python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, since each of your columns has a non-numeric value in the first non-header row, pandas automatically parses the entire column to be text.

One workaround is to skip the text row like this:

`df=pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=",",skiprows=[1])`

Then when you try to plot it will work just using:

`df['coal content'].plot()`

[image]

Of course, this means you don't read in the metadata in the first row, but hopefully that doesn't cause too much trouble for you.